# как сделать чтобы по второму нажатию стили возвращались обратно

Tags: javascript, html, css

по нажатию оно меняет фон на черный, но по следующему нажатию не возвращает обратно

```js
theme.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if(document.body.style.backgroundColor !== '#000'){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
    }
    else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    }
});
```

```html
<button id="theme">Change Theme</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Если вы откроете девтулз в браузере, то увидите, что получается, когда вы назначаете стили:

```
<body style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
```

То есть браузер записывает не именно ваш цвет, а переводит в другой формат. Именно поэтому обратно цвет не меняется. Так что один вариант -- это исправить на другое название цвета, как написал ΝNL993.

Но обычно такие вещи делают через изменение классов стилей. Вот так:

```js
const THEME_CLASS = 'body_dark';
const body = document.body;

theme.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  body.classList.toggle(THEME_CLASS);
});
```

```css
.body_dark {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<button id="theme">Change Theme</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно вам стоит использовать [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), чтобы все цвета были в одном формате. (`window.getComputedStyle` возвращает формат цветов RGB)

```js
theme.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let styles = window.getComputedStyle(document.body)

  if(styles.backgroundColor !== 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="theme">Change Theme</button>
```

#### Внимание

Вам также стоит перейти на формат цветов RGB/RGBA, вместо HEX'а, так вам будет проще работать с цветами.